# Is it possible to set out user status message in teams through graph API?

Tags: powershell, api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I want to set user status message in teams using graph api and I saw this code but it's not working for me is there any solution that could help??

"@odata. context":"https://graph.mic.."

"id": "f599db41-7474-416a-acb1-88f9e

"availability": "Available"

"activity" :"Available"

"outofOfficeSettings": {"message": "oof mes"
"is0utofoffice":true }

Note: the availability & activity is working and has been updating in teams but the part below is not working for me""

or is there any way using graph api that I could set teams status message from bambooHR direct to teams?

Comment: The quotes after the id and isOutOfOffice=true are missing. Maybe that's your problem?

Comment: this available in Microsoft website